# How to search based on relevance in solr?

Tags: solr

I am querying solr based on a number of filters such as content name, size but one of these filters is relevance. I am using SolrQuery API to add filters to solr.

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.set("q", mQueryString);
query.addFilterQuery(Name);
```

But i am not able to find value to put for relevance.

How can i make search happen based on content relevance.Can anybody help?

Comment: what do you mean by "content relevance" . By default lucene uses a TFIDF similarity to score document relevance : https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html . If you want a different kind of sorting please make it clear in your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to search based on relevancy score using SolrQuery. For getting results sorted based on solr default relevance order, i passed 'score' parameter to solr query and it worked.

```
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();    
solrQuery.setParam("q", keywords);
solrQuery.setParam("q.op", "AND");
solrQuery.setParam("df", "text");
solrQuery.setParam("qt", "/select");
SolrQuery.SortClause  sortClause = new SortClause("score", ORDER.desc);
solrQuery.addSort(sortClause);
```

Answer (score 0):

Relevance of search results is something that is calculated during search, and it deppends on two things: the query and the content of search results. 
The exact formula upon which the relevance is calculated is called TF-IDF, explained in detail here http://www.tfidf.com/

If you wish, you can make different fields in Solr (title, subject) to be scored higher than the content of the page, thus making query hits there more relevant. This is called field boosting and is explained here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_make_.22superman.22_in_the_title_field_score_higher_than_in_the_subject_field